# How can I remove the descriptions from the registration page programatically?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

Using the custom module mentioned here https://www.drupal.org/node/754542#comment-2775706 I was able to remove the descriptions from the user login page.

```
function alterlogin_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name']['#description'] = t('');
  $form['pass'] = array('#type'  => 'password',
                        '#title' => t('Password'),
                        '#description' => t(''),
                        '#required' => TRUE,
                       );
}
```

however when I try

```
function alterlogin_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name']['#description'] = t('');
}
```

the description stays the same. I know it's targetting the page because

```
function alterlogin_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name']['#description'] = t('');
  $form['pass'] = array('#type'  => 'password',
                        '#title' => t('Password'),
                        '#description' => t(''),
                        '#required' => TRUE,
                       );
}
```

creates a password field on the registration page (that I assume does nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is just a bit off.

```
$form['name']['#description'] = t('');
```

Should be:

```
$form['account']['name']['#description'] = t('');
```

If your ever unsure of what an array looks like, always a good idea to download [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and dpm item so you can see what the structure looks like.